# Every time I run the app the buttons work, but only in a sequential order

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Travelling.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);



            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Rectangles.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Squares.class);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                            Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                            button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Triangles.class);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                                    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
                                    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Circles.class);
                                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                                            Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
                                            button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Cube.class);
                                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                                                    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
                                                    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Cuboid.class);
                                                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                                                            Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
                                                            button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),SimpleInterest.class);
                                                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                                                                    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
                                                                    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),UsefulFacts.class);
                                                                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);







        }
    });
}{

}
```

});}});}});}});}});}});}});}});}}

Ok to begin with...... my app works..........However anytime i press a random button lets say button3, nothing happens. I've noticed that to get the buttons to work i have to start pressing the button at the beginning then go down (sequentially that is).............When this is done the buttons start working. My question is: How can I make each button work with a direct touch(That is without having to press the list of buttons from top to bottom to get there)

Comment: You're setting each listener in the previous button's listener.  Move all the listeners to the top level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an algorithm like:

```
      Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Rectangles.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

then you are creating a click handler for `button3` when you click on `button2`. This is not correct, you should define the click listener of `button3` outside the scope of the click listener of `button2`. The same applies for your other buttons, as you have consistently repeated the same mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to let your `Activity` handle the `onClick` event, and **add all the listeners at the same level**, as opposed to what you are doing now which requires you to press the first to button to reach the line of code that sets the `OnClickListener` for the second button and so on.

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(...);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(...);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(...);
```